# Наследование шаблонных классов

Tags: c++

Есть проблема, показывает ошибку `error C2228: выражение слева от ".name" должно представлять класс, структуру или объединение`. Должно вывести тип данных. Код взят с видеоурока:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n6GMKC40gC0

```
Что не так?

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class T1>
class TypeSize
{
public:
    TypeSize(T1 value)
    {
        this->value = value;
    }
    void DataTypeSize()
    {
        cout << "value = " << sizeof(value) << endl;
    }
protected:
    T1 value;
};

template<class T1>
class TypeInfo : public TypeSize<T1> 
{
public:
    TypeInfo(T1 value) : TypeSize<T1>(value)
    {

    }
    void ShowTypeName()
    {
        cout << "Название типа " << typeid(value).name() << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    double a = 2;

    TypeInfo<double> c(a);
    c.ShowTypeName();
    c.DataTypeSize();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Какой компилятор Вы используете (версию тоже укажите, пожалуйста)?

Comment: Извините, не подскажите как узнать какой версии у меня компилятор?

Comment: Если у Вас Linux-based ОС или BSD - ```сс --version```. А вообще, посмотрите 3-ю ссылку, мне кажется, Вы должны там найти ответ на свой вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

```
typeid(value).name();
```

Замените на:

```
typeid(T1).name()
```

Или явно укажите:

```
   typeid(TypeSize<T1>::value).name()
```

P.S. Я обьяснил не так как хотел, поэтому уберу обьснения

Comment: Он с выражениями тоже работает: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cf28061c7eb35278 Дело в чем-то еще...

Comment: @ HolyBlackCat, работал бы, если  бы обьект не имел тип аргумента шаблона

Comment: Еще альтернатива: `typeid(this->value).name()`. Оставлю тут ссылку на объяснения: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10722606/why-do-i-need-to-use-scope-resolution-in-template-inheritance

Comment: да, и так тоже правильно, но обьяснения оставлю другим, поскольку это у меня плохо получается